# skip over a value in a loop and then continue to loop?

Tags: vba

I need to be able to run a loop starting at 0, have it identify a certain value (in this case piecenumblack) and then skip that value, and then continue the loop until it hits 11. I'm really unsure what type of loop to use and I've had no success with a Do, While, or For loop.

```
  Dim piecenumblack As Integer
            For i = 0 To piecenumblack


            Next
            For i = 11 To piecenumblack Step -1

            Next
```

Comment: why not just do the full loop and then place an `if` i == piecenumblack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add an If to the inside of the loop:

```
  Dim piecenumblack As Integer
  piecenumblack = 3
  For i = 0 To 11
      If i <> piecenumblack then
         'Do Code
      End If
  Next
```

This would then skip doing any code when `i = 3` then continue on with 4,5,6..11.

Comment: For clarification- That wouldn't cause the loop just to stop at whatever piecenumblack was and just not do the rest, correct? If piecenumblack = 3, and then the For Loop hits 3, would it cause the For Loop to just stop there and not do 4, 5, 6 ...12?

Comment: @5kong that is correct, If `piecenumblack` was 5 then it would skip doing anything when `i` = 5 and do all the rest.

Comment: Thanks Scott! you were of great help :)